# How to overwrite the data I have passed inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

***TLDR:***

How can I change the value of an array which I have appended via an `each` loop to a button?

***Background story:***

I am creating an image gallery with all kinds of different pictures. When a user logs in, I retrieve the data from the database (via ajax) to show the user his or her uploaded images etc.

However during this process I use a loop for the images to append all the images to a div.

When the user clicks on a loaded image (by now the document is 'ready' -> loaded) the data retrieved alongside the image is shown in a `modal`. Like this: (note: This is a very short version, there are a lot of input fields etc. created this way, but it's pretty useless to show).

*- Images is a multidimensional array.*
It looks like this:

```
images = [
    0 => [
      0 => 'here is the title',
      1 => 'Here comes the image path',
      2 => 'the ID of the image',
      3 => 'This is the accessibility which I will later down the road try to change'
    ],
   1 => [
      //repeat the above basically, but with different values
    ]
]
```

And the way I create a `div` box for each image is as follow: (note, this is a short version, the main problem is the `evenListener` and not the way I create the `div`. So I did not include that part of code)

```
//the images here is an array!!
$(images).each(function(key, array) {
        let image = document.createElement('img');
            image.setAttribute('class', 'rounded resizeForcer');
            image.setAttribute('src', array[3]);
            image.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
            image.setAttribute('data-target', '#previewImageBig');
            image.addEventListener('click', function() {
                previewImage(array); //when clicked on the image, a modal will open up, while the modal opens the data will be passed to the modal and from there on I show the data
            });
});
```

When the user clicks on the image itself it brings the data from the multidimensional array along to show and append in the `modal`. However the user can update the way the image is being accessed by outsiders (let's say you want to upload an image with a token, so it is only URL accessible).

***Problem:***

When I update the accessibility of the image as user, it should send back a new link for me to copy paste if I ever want my friends to see the picture and this link should override the link that was set during the array in the `addEventListener`. So let's say I have 3 images, that would mean I have index 0, 1 and 2 in the images array with 4 different indexes inside each one of them. What I would like to achieve, but am failing at, is to grab the `array` (basically the index I append when creating the `div`) and change the value of the third index. So when I click on the desired `image` to pop up my `modal`, it'll have the value overwritten, instead of showing the data it had fetched prior to me changing the accessibility (index 3) reference: The first bit of code where the multidimensional array structure is shown.

Comment: Are you trying to reorder the array after a user changes it?

Comment: Not really, I am trying to just change the array index 3 (the third index is always the index which should be changed) when the user clicks on 'change accessibility' it should send the new way of accessing the image via URL, so you can send it to your friend for example to view it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to change the index 3 value of an image based on user input.  The trick is to keep track of the index and "sub-index", then use those indexes later. You didn't provide a working example, so I created a very simplified example of what you're trying to do; complete with comments to help you understand what is going on.

```
var images = [
  [
    'here is the title',
    'Here comes the image path',
    'the ID of the image',
     'This is the accessibility which I will later down the road try to change'
  ],
  [
    'here is the title 2',
    'Here comes the image path 2',
    'the ID of the image 2',
    'This is the accessibility which I will later down the road try to change 2'
  ],
];
// loops through each image
$.each(images, function(index, image) {
  // create a variable where the html of each "image" will be held
  var html = '';
  // loop through each array item in the current array
  $.each(image, function(subindex, value) {
    // builds an input for each "image" value and holds current index and subindex inside an html attribute that will be referenced later
    html += '<input type="text"  value="' + value + '" data-index="' + index + '" data-subindex="' + subindex + '">';
  });
  // create a button that will "save" the changes in each input, event listener for this is created later
  html += '<input type="button" class="sub-button" value="Save" style="background-color:yellow;">';
  // create a box container that will hold each "image's" html, only for this example
  $('#box').append('<div class="sub-box" style="border:1px solid black; padding:10px; margin:10px;">' + html + '</div>');
});
// create an event listener for all "Save" buttons that were created
$('.sub-button').click(function() {
  // clears any old status messages, only for this example
  $('#status').html('');
  // find all the inputs inside the same container of this button
  var inputs = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]');
  // loops through each input
  inputs.each(function() {
    // creates temporary object that holds the attributes of each input
    var attr = {
      'index': $(this).attr('data-index'),
      'subindex':$(this).attr('data-subindex'),
      'value': $(this).val()
    };
    // reference the images array again, but with the index, subindex, and value, this is what updates the each subarray value
    images[attr.index][attr.subindex] = attr.value;
    // output the changes that were done, for this example only
    $('#status').append('images[' + attr.index + '][' + attr.subindex + '] is now "' + attr.value + '".<br>');
  });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/re7m9f35/

Keep in mind, that the changes here are temporary, you'll have to figure something else out to retain the changes your users make.

Comment: Well, I tested your answer and it seems to work. I however opted to go for a different route (before noticing you had responded) by simply making a global object (not the best practice, I know) and change the values there...